# sbt native packager and app writable directory

Tags: scala, sbt, sbt-native-packager

Using the sbt-native-packager plugin, what's the best approach to have a app-writable directory? In my configuration i use `enablePlugins(JavaServerAppPackaging, SystemdPlugin, DebianPlugin, UniversalPlugin)` and it all works well except my app needs to write some files for its own functioning, under /usr/share/package-name/ sounds wrong but then i wonder where and how is best to do that, also if i should use debain postinst scripts of try to alter directory permissions from the mappings of the universal pluin.

Comment: What kind of files need you to write ?

Comment: Data for a bitcoin wallet, the files are accessed every ~30s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding a new writeable directory in a linux distribution means adding a mapping to the `linuxPackageMappings` [(documentation)](http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/formats/linux.html#package-mappings).

```
linuxPackageMappings += packageTemplateMapping(
  s"/opt/${(packageName in Linux).value}"
)().withUser((daemonUser in Linux).value)
   .withGroup((daemonGroup in Linux).value)
   .withPerms("755")
```

You can see this with the old sbt syntax in use for the [JavaServerApp plugin](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-native-packager/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/typesafe/sbt/packager/archetypes/JavaServerApplication.scala#L53-L57).

**Note:** You should **NOT** set the `/usr/share/<packageName>` directory writeable. It contains the executables and config files and should only be modifiable for the root user.

cheers,
Muki